# What is the most convenient way to organize dependencies from paclets?

Tags: packages, scripting, paclets, development

Do you have any ideas on how to most conveniently and easily organize package dependencies for Wolfram Language projects. I would like to have something like a list of packages in projects for .Net that are automatically checked and updated. Or something similar to `package.json` for JS projects. Understandably, I could always add an initialization cell or add lines with package installs and imports to `Kernel/init.wl`, but it's the structure and design of dependencies for the project that I'm most interested in.

Comment: Have you tried the tools in [Wolfram Workbench](https://www.wolfram.com/workbench/)?

Comment: Yes, I have used Wolfram Workbench a lot. I like what's done there in the style of Java projects, but unfortunately few users use this IDE. So I'm thinking about how to make the most convenient configuration of dependencies if there is only Wolrfam Engine

Comment: Hmm... it seems that there should be a paclet for this or a WFR function. (Have not checked...)

Comment: This is particularly important for the PacletSymbol to not permanently install any paclet that the main paclet depends on. Otherwise, any manual initialization would break its promise of being a clean, current session-only execution.